# Filter a Dataframe if values in a list are contained as either a string/substring in a column. Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, string, list, filter

I am familiar with filtering a dataframe if the value of a column can be found in a list, but I can't figure out how to implement the reverse case, iterating through values in a list to see if those values are contained in the column value.

something like this:

```
dataframe = dataframe[dataframe[column].apply(lambda x: f for f in filter_list in x)]
```

Such that, I'm looking to see if each value, f, in the filter_list, can be found in x, the value from the dataframe[column]

I cannot use re.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take the time to read this post on how to [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) as well as how to provide a [minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly